# Jquery ReplaceWith() using conditional function not behaving as I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jQuery and I'm using an online tutorial.  I'm at the portion where we are learning about the `replaceWith()` function and how it can use another function as it's return results.  Looking at the teachers code I don't understand how it's working.

**jQuery**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#example p").replaceWith(replacementFn);
    function replacementFn() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf("1") != -1) {
            return "<p>This is paragraph uno</p>";
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">
    <p class="a">This is paragraph 1</p>
    <p id="para1">This is paragraph 2</p>
    <p class="b">This is paragraph 3</p>
    <p id="para4" lang="en-us">This is paragraph 4</p>
    <p id="para5" lang="en-gb">This is paragraph 5</p>
</div>
```

As the code is it works like I was shown.  One paragraph is replaced with the `"This is paragraph uno"`.   But once I change the `indexOf("1")` to `indexOf("6")` everything in the Example div gets wiped out.  What I don't understand is why when at least one paragraph meets the check everything works fine.  But once none of them meet the check everything gets wiped out.

Why doesn't the original code wipe everything but the paragraph that matches the check?

Comment: This is odd. If you add `else { return this.outerHTML }`, they're all restored, so it seems that when there's no match, the `undefined` return value is wiping them out. I have no idea why. Seems buggy.

Comment: adding the `else { return this.outerHTML }` solved the issue thank you.  But I am still very curious of the why.

Comment: Yeah, not sure. It should behave more consistently IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If would appear that [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/332fd941b4ae80e8ca5e5a20aca91806038f4816/src/manipulation.js#L463) in the jQuery source is the cause. If the replacement function returns something unusable for all items in the set, then the entire set is deleted from the DOM:

```
// Force removal if there was no new content (e.g., from empty arguments)
return arg && (arg.length || arg.nodeType) ? this : this.remove();
```

I would say that this conditional replacement that you are using seems like a loophole of some sort, and it is not documented in the jQuery documentation.

I suggest filtering the items you want to replace before carrying out the replacement:

```
$("#example p").filter(pickItems).replaceWith(replacementFn);

function pickItems() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("1") !== -1;
} 

function replacementFn() {
    return "<p>This is paragraph uno</p>";
}
```

Alternatively, you can conditionally return the new content, or the original items when not replacing them:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#example p").replaceWith(replacementFn);

    function replacementFn() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf("6") !== -1) {
            return "<p>This is paragraph uno</p>";
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
    <p class="a">This is paragraph 1</p>
    <p id="para1">This is paragraph 2</p>
    <p class="b">This is paragraph 3</p>
    <p id="para4" lang="en-us">This is paragraph 4</p>
    <p id="para5" lang="en-gb">This is paragraph 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That would explain it.  Thank you

Comment: Well there it is. How sloppy of you jQuery. +1 nice find.

Comment: Looks like this is the commit that broke it: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/642e9a45579cfa90861b8ea71a95dd077775caaf#diff-169760a97de5c86a886842060321d2c8 Someone (not me) should file a bug report. ;-)

Comment: I just posted in the forums asking if this is a bug or not.  If it is I'll do what is needed.   Thank you for your help.

Comment: @squint Looking at the before/after there, it looks like this behavior may have already been there in the "before" version. Basically, it seems that if the function never returns something that can be treated as a node, the callback in `replaceWith()` is never called, and it has to be called at least once to prevent `this.remove()` from happening. That seems to have been true in the "before" version. It does seem like both `replaceWith` and `domManip` are a complete mess of mutability, but I will not claim that I know better than the jQuery devs.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but in the old version there's an `i` counter that gets incremented in the `domManip` callback, so that if there's at least one argument passed, `i` increments and prevents the `.remove()` operation.  `var next = args[ i++ ],`Testing with jQuery 1.10, the correct behavior is observed. http://jsbin.com/vuduziraza/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: ...oops, screwed that up. It's the `1.9.1` version that seems to be the last working version... http://jsbin.com/vuduziraza/5/edit?html,js,console,output Anyway, I'm sure they'll get it fixed.

Comment: @squint Yeah, your first JSBin link had an invalid jQuery URL so jQuery wasn't doing anything. :) Looks like 1.9.1 doesn't have the `this.remove()` part, so that explains the difference.